# Why did this character lose his power at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-resurrections

Near the end of *The Matrix Resurrections*, The Analyst lost his ability to manipulate time, a power we saw in earlier scenes where Neo was completely helpless.

Why did that ability go? Is it because both him and Trinity are now awake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before he slows time we see the Déjà Vu black cat.

We see him try to reach the cat, and fail to do much, during the SWAT fight.

The implication is likely that the time manipulation power is connected to Déjà Vu.

As the analyst explains, the friction between Neo and Trinity grants them power.

> The key to it all? You. And her. Quietly yearning for what you don’t have, while dreading losing what you do.

As such, the black cat that is the symbol of déjà vu in the original matrix for Trinity and Neo probably made a potent symbol for tapping into bullet time and rewinding time.